# Get value from multi mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I have this code:

```
struct VotesInfo {
    string name;
    uint256 voteCount;
    bool enabled;
    uint256 check;
}

mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => VotesInfo)) private _votelist;
```

How can I get the info from the mapping if I know only the second mapping key (uint256) and not the address? As I understood foreach is not an option. Also new to solidity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't! The second mapping `(uint256 => VotesInfo)` is the value of the first mapping. To access that value, you must know its key (the address).

Comment: I had a feeling it is like that but also hoped for a workaround :) Thanks!